# RegEx reconstruction with replace with groups

Tags: c#, regex, replace, regex-group

We are doing URL rewrite and user can type url as

```
 somesite.com/category6/page.aspx
```

Now we want to rewrite the url as

```
 somesite.com/6/category/page.aspx.
```

We already have bunch of regex for url rewrite however replace string is static, we wanted follow the same pattern and not to customize for this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

**rewrite rule**:

(category)([0-9]+)(/?.*)

**parsing**:

{R:0} category6/page.aspx

{R:1} category

{R:2} 6

{R:3} /page.aspx

**using the rules**:

{R:2}/{R:1}{R:3}